# Developing a wordpress template generation through a plugin

Tags: templates, wordpress

I am developing a wordpress plugin which generates a team page. So i need to add a template page team.php. Can the process be automated independent of the theme, or the user have to be urged for copying the file manually to the templates directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to copy the page like that. Ask the user to create a normal page with only a shortcode in it which you can replace with you content.

That's the standard way to do these things. This page will tell you how to do it : http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

Example :

```
//In your functions.php file
function create_team_page($atts, $content = null){
    //$team_data = generate data here 
    return $team_data;
}
add_shortcode('team_page', 'create_team_page');
```

The user would simply create a new page with wordpress and put the shortcode `[team_data]` in the contents. Your hook would replace it with content.

Answer (score 1):

Answering the original question, yes, you can add page templates from a plugin, independant of any themes.

Here is my code solution (inspired by Tom McFarlin).

This is designed for a plugin (the template files are searched for in the root directory of the plugin). This can be changed if desired - check out my full tutorial http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/ for greater detail on this solution. These files are also in exactly the same format as if they were to be included directly in a theme.

To customise, simply edit the following code block within the __construct method;

```
   $this->templates = array(
       'goodtobebad-template.php'     => 'It\'s Good to Be Bad',
   );
```

**Full code;**

```
class PageTemplater {

    /**
     * A Unique Identifier
     */
     protected $plugin_slug;

    /**
     * A reference to an instance of this class.
     */
    private static $instance;

    /**
     * The array of templates that this plugin tracks.
     */
    protected $templates;


    /**
     * Returns an instance of this class. 
     */
    public static function get_instance() {

            if( null == self::$instance ) {
                    self::$instance = new PageTemplater();
            } 

            return self::$instance;

    } 

    /**
     * Initializes the plugin by setting filters and administration functions.
     */
    private function __construct() {

            $this->templates = array();


            // Add a filter to the attributes metabox to inject template into the cache.
            add_filter(
                'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args',
                 array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ) 
            );


            // Add a filter to the save post to inject out template into the page cache
            add_filter(
                'wp_insert_post_data', 
                array( $this, 'register_project_templates' ) 
            );


            // Add a filter to the template include to determine if the page has our 
            // template assigned and return it's path
            add_filter(
                'template_include', 
                array( $this, 'view_project_template') 
            );


            // Add your templates to this array.
            $this->templates = array(
                    'goodtobebad-template.php'     => 'It\'s Good to Be Bad',
            );

    } 


    /**
     * Adds our template to the pages cache in order to trick WordPress
     * into thinking the template file exists where it doens't really exist.
     *
     */

    public function register_project_templates( $atts ) {

            // Create the key used for the themes cache
            $cache_key = 'page_templates-' . md5( get_theme_root() . '/' . get_stylesheet() );

            // Retrieve the cache list. 
            // If it doesn't exist, or it's empty prepare an array
            $templates = wp_get_theme()->get_page_templates();
            if ( empty( $templates ) ) {
                    $templates = array();
            } 

            // New cache, therefore remove the old one
            wp_cache_delete( $cache_key , 'themes');

            // Now add our template to the list of templates by merging our templates
            // with the existing templates array from the cache.
            $templates = array_merge( $templates, $this->templates );

            // Add the modified cache to allow WordPress to pick it up for listing
            // available templates
            wp_cache_add( $cache_key, $templates, 'themes', 1800 );

            return $atts;

    } 

    /**
     * Checks if the template is assigned to the page
     */
    public function view_project_template( $template ) {

            global $post;

            if (!isset($this->templates[get_post_meta( 
                $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true 
            )] ) ) {

                    return $template;

            } 

            $file = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__). get_post_meta( 
                $post->ID, '_wp_page_template', true 
            );

            // Just to be safe, we check if the file exist first
            if( file_exists( $file ) ) {
                    return $file;
            } 
            else { echo $file; }

            return $template;

    } 


} 

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( 'PageTemplater', 'get_instance' ) );
```

Check out my tutorial on this for more info.

http://www.wpexplorer.com/wordpress-page-templates-plugin/

I hope this helps you in what you want to do :)